# Are there benefits to learning to write with your non-dominant hand?

Tags: perception, personality, cognitive-neuroscience, motor, lateralization

There are some articles on the web that recommend learning to write with your non-dominant hand to [get in touch with your inner child](http://www.acaconvention.org/pdf/Inner_Child_Writing_by_Michele.pdf) or [a higher power](http://www.dailykos.com/story/2012/03/24/1077569/-A-message-from-the-non-dominant-hand), [increase your creativity and be more open-minded](http://www.nwitimes.com/niche/shore/health/using-your-other-hand-benefits-your-brain/article_6da931ea-b64f-5cc2-9583-e78f179c2425.html) or some such thing. I don't usually believe random stuff from the internet, but:

One of my drawing teachers told us to try drawing with the non-dominant hand. What I discovered was that I was very much better at getting proportions right with the non-dominant hand. I only had to use the dominant hand to clean up the shaky lines, because my non-dominant hand has poor fine motor control.

So there is obviously something that happens, when I use the "other" hand, something that has to do with how my perceptions are processed and my hand movement is controlled. But these "switches" while I draw are just temporary. What is sometimes recommended on some websites is a more fundamental change: to switch hands for *all* tasks.

**Is there research on the effects of switching hands for all or certain tasks?**

*I have no idea which tags I should select. Please edit my tags, if you feel you know better.*

Answer (score 12):

Yes, there are benefits, but I don't think it requires long-term switches.  Studies have used this as a manipulation to try and increase self control and have found that it decrease aggression.  Based on this, once one has mastered using the non-dominant hand, it seems like the benefit of continuing to use that hand might be over (as it no longer requires effort).

See: Denson, T. F., Capper, M. M., Oaten, M., Friese, M., & Schofield, T. P. (2011). Self-control training decreases aggression in response to provocation in aggressive individuals. Journal of Research in Personality, 45(2), 252–256. doi:10.1016/j.jrp.2011.02.001

Comment: "Our findings provide evidence for persisting differences in the functional neuroanatomy of handwriting between right-handers and converted left-handers, despite decades of right-hand writing." http://www.jneurosci.org/content/22/7/2816.long The brains of converted left-handers are more active than non-converted right- or left-handers, and they are active in a "left-hand way": "brain regions involved in planning movement stubbornly refuse to switch, and continue to act like those of left-handers in people who have switched to right-handedness". http://www.jneurosci.org/content/27/29/7847.full

Comment: +1 for the the new info -- didn't know this was used as a manipulation. Very interesting. But it seems like some differences persist, though it apparently remains unclear what effects these differences have.

Comment: https://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-3820189/Could-forcing-write-hands-make-smarter-Experts-remain-divided-bizarre-brain-training-technique.html